# PictureBox.Load method loading images from the internet slow at first request

Tags: c#, .net, image, picturebox

I have posted a question about a similar issue before, and managed to fix that by setting the "Proxy" property of the object to null. However, with PictureBox.Load(String) this is a different issue. As far as I know, there's no Proxy property for that.

And so, the first call of `picPreview.Load(URL);` takes a while.

Is anyone aware of a method to set the Proxy application-wide, or for a PictureBox?

Thanks.

PS: `picPreview.ImageLocation = URL;` does the same as `picPreview.Load(URL);`.

Comment: There's a *lot* of code that needs to be loaded to make this happen.  Google 'slow cold start' to see what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by downloading the image into a MemoryStream first.

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Proxy = null;
        byte[] bFile = wc.DownloadData(URL);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bFile);
        Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
        picPreview.Image = img;
```